# Bridge eth0 to WiFi hotspot as a client

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi, ethernet, bridge, wifi-hotspot

So, I have a raspberry pi4 that I am using as a WiFi signal booster.

I have a long range external USB WiFi dongle (wlan0) that is picking up the signal.

I am using the pi’s internal WiFi (wlan1) to create it’s own AP network with the help of Create_AP.

All of this works wonderfully. My question is, can I somehow bridge the eth0 on the pi to the AP hotspot network (wlan1)? This way I can get the internet to a device that is Ethernet only?

This might be a little confusing, as I have my external usb set as wlan0 instead of the internal WiFi.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want cable-only devices to get Internet, you can use linux-router ( https://github.com/garywill/linux-router ) (It's NAT, not bridged)

```
lnxrouter -i eth0
```

That's it. That script makes that simple. (BTW, the script is a fork of create_ap, which added support for sharing Internet to ethernet interfaces)